# Convert microseconds into format string with timezone

Tags: python, datetime

I need to convert a value in microseconds to the format `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` and apply timezone information to adjust the output. I tried:

```
datatime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('format')
```

but that is not timezone aware. How do I apply timezone information when converting from microseconds to a date and time string?

Comment: Do you know what timezone the microsecond value is in?

Comment: Yes timestamp and timezone values I know.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the timestamp ("seconds since the epoch") to time in UTC as a naive datetime object:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = 1422025533
utc_time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
print("Time is = %s" % utc_time)
# -> Time is = 2015-01-23 15:05:33
```

If you want to get the value in a specific timezone as an aware datetime object; you should use `pytz` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
timestamp = 1422025533
london_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz)
print("Time is = %s" % london_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'))
# -> Time is = 2015-01-23 15:05:33 GMT+0000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sebastian. This works and I can sleep peacefully :-)

Answer (score -1):

I think [Delorean](http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is the right lib you should use.

> Delorean is a library for clearing up the inconvenient truths that arise dealing with datetimes in

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

EST = "US/Eastern"
UTC = "UTC"

d = datetime.utcnow()
utc = timezone(UTC)
est = timezone(EST)
d = utc.localize(d)
d = est.normalize(d)
print d
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer . Could you pls explain little bit on these steps that we do here. I have timezone value as "GMT" and timestamp value 1422025533. The expected value is "2015-01-23 15:05:33". When I apply the above logic, I may not get this string.

Comment: continuation to above comment: - The script in two different machine gives two different answers - in one machine I got "2015-01-23 15:05:33" and another one "2015-01-23 20:35:33"

Comment: it is a rather convoluted way to get `datetime.now(timezone('US/Eastern'))`